# Plotting points over an image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot `p1, p2, p3` over an image, I'm not sure how to do that efficiently and I'm probably missing something, here are the values of the points:
[image]

**This is what I've tried:**

```
pts = load('myFile.mat')
p1 = pts.p1
p2 = pts.p2
p3 = pts.p3
im = imread ('myImg.JPG') % Loads the image compEx2 .JPG
imagesc (im) % Displays the image
plot(p1,p2, p3, 'r*', 'LineWidth', 2, 'MarkerSize', 2);
hold on
```

The first problem I have is, I'm not sure how to plot all the 3 variables `p1,p2,p3` in the image, because it looks like they have `x` and `y` values already in the same variable, how do I extract it to plot it?

Also, the points aren't plotted in the image if I try something like:

```
plot(p1,p2, 'r*', 'LineWidth', 2, 'MarkerSize', 2);
```

It just plots `p1` and `p2`. Not sure how to add `p3` into the plot too. and how to make it show on the image.

After using max's suggestion w/ this code:

```
imagesc (im) % Displays the image
colormap gray % changes the colormap of the current image to gray scale
hold on
plot([p1;p2;p3], 'r*', 'LineWidth', 4, 'MarkerSize', 4);
```

The points are plotted in the edge of the image:

[image]

Comment: But each of those `p` are 3 points. Is this what you expected? Is the first column the `` value, the second the `y`? Do you want to essentially plot 9 points?

Comment: concatenate the variables for plotting `plot([p1;p2;p3])` and use the `hold on` after the first plot (which is `imagesc` in your case)

Comment: @max I did that, it plots the point just on the left edge of the image

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, I want to plot these 9 points on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the `x` and `y` coordinates:

```
% merge vectors
P = [p1;p2;p3];
% split coordinates
x = P(:,1);
y = P(:,2);

% open figure with image
imshow(im);
% plot points
hold on
plot(x,y,'*')
hold off
```

If you don't provide them individually to the `plot` command, it will assume that they are lines (of which you only want to plot the markers) and take the index as the value for the `x`-axis

Comment: Thanks max! wasn;t sure how to achieve the splitting to x and y

Answer (score 1):

Unpack them into coordinates:

```
x(1:3)=p1(:,1);
x(4:6)=p2(:,1);
x(7:9)=p3(:,1);

y(1:3)=p1(:,2);
y(4:6)=p2(:,2);
y(7:9)=p3(:,2);
```

then

```
plot(x,y,...)
```

Careful with image coordinates, maybe those points are in `xy` coordinates not image coordinates.